# WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync not working in UWP

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

My selected characterstic property returns Indicate but still WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(cccdValue) does not return Success status

This is the piece of code:
 status = await selectedCharacteristic.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(cccdValue);//writes cccd to the ble device to enable indication or notification

```
status = await selectedCharacteristic.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(cccdValue);//writes cccd to the ble device to enable indication or notification

 if (status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
                    {
                        AddValueChangedHandler();
                        rootPage.NotifyUser("Successfully subscribed for value changes", NotifyType.StatusMessage);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rootPage.NotifyUser($"Error registering for value changes: {status}", NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
                    }
```

It always goes in else condition.I have put Indicate property True but still it does not work.

Please help, any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One thing to be aware of, that's not well documented, is that the peripheral needs to have a writable Gatt CCCD Characteristic Descriptor with a very specific UUID (**00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb**) to be technically compliant.  Android and iOS will not fail if the peripheral is non-compliant, but UWP currently will throw this exception.  There does not appear to be any way to get UWP to work with a non-compliant device.

If you are making a peripheral, be aware that no matter what UUID's you use for anything, the CCCD needs be the 2902 UUID.  Otherwise you'll get this UWP exception.

Answer (score 1):

Does the characteristic support Writing?

```
GattCharacteristicProperties properties = characteristic.CharacteristicProperties;
            if (properties.HasFlag(GattCharacteristicProperties.Write) || properties.HasFlag(GattCharacteristicProperties.WriteWithoutResponse))
            {
               //writing is supported..
            }
```

If it does:

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.genericattributeprofile.gattcommunicationstatus)

There are four statuses:

- Access Denied
- Device Unreachable
- Success
- Protocol error

As you have not posted the status, I can't give you a precise answer... If it's Protocol Error, you need to provide more information on the device.
Try this:

1. Access Denied: Retry, by getting the characteristic without using the Bluetooth Cache

   ```
           var characteristics = await selectedService.GetCharacteristicsForUuidAsync(characteristicUuid, BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);
           selectedCharacteristic = characteristics[0];
           status = await selectedCharacteristic.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(cccdValue);
   ```

Then retry writing.

2. Device Unreachable: The connection was lost. Either the device is too far away or you need to reconnect. Recreate the device object and retry.

   ```
          BluetoothLEDevice device = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceId); 
           .....
   ```

Comment: The status is "unreachable". The BLE device is very near to the client and I on and off my laptop bluetooth multiple times but it still shows unreachable

Comment: My code somehow does not work with Uncached mode, i dont know why. When I write GattDeviceServicesResult result = await bluetoothLeDevice.GetGattServicesAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Cached); it shows Device Unreachable

Comment: Did you try to recreate the device/service/characteristic object, just before the trying to write to the characteristic? @ShikharTandon